# How to properly destroy CKEditor instance?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am running CKeditor 3.4 on a pretty simple page. I am having a problem (sometimes) where when I call `document.main_form.submit()`, it will not send along the contents of the textarea. After some reading, it sounds like CKeditor is not destroying properly. I tried to manually destroy it before I save the form, but wasn't able to call it. The weird thing is, it works sometimes, but not others. I'm on Chrome, so that may be screwing with things, but the same thing happens in Firefox.

How can I properly destroy the CKeditor so that it always sends the textarea data in POST. Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had this problem.  What a pain.

To properly destroy the editor instance, try

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName) CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName.destroy();
```

From the documentation [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy)

I solved the missing content issue by assigning the contents of the editor to a hidden field prior to postback.  I'm using ASP.Net, but it should work universally.

in the client-side click handler of the submit button, call

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName)
    document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = CKEDITOR.instances.getData();
```

Comment: how do I know what 'myInstanceName' is? Is this the id of the editor?

Answer (score 16):

I once used angularjs ui-router with one CKEDITOR instance for each sub-view. I used the following solution to clear the instances every time I load the ui-view

```
for(name in CKEDITOR.instances)
{
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy()
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution. In my case each time the user visits the route where the editor is loaded, the instance name changes....from editor1 to editor2 etc. Since I can't easily predict the instance name, looping through them all like this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In my situation

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName.destroy();
```

didn't help, because I'd opened CKEditor in `jquery dialog` on double click on some item. When I closed editor and then opened them again, my code crashed.
Solution was using

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName.destroy(false);
```

which updated DOM element ([link to documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy)).

Comment: We open our CKEditors in a jquery dialog too.  We were using `CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName.destroy(true);` which also caused our code to crash due to the error "TypeError: a is null".  However, switching to `false` didn't solve our problem.  Had to wrap this line of code in a try / catch

Answer (score 6):

use this simple code.Note my text area id is **editor1**.

or You can also check it with `console.log(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1);`

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances.editor1) {
     CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`for(name in CKEDITOR.instances){
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy()
}`

Use to code to destroy all the instances created by ckeditor

Answer (score -1):

the solution that finally did work.

The issue was if you destroy a ckeditor and the subsequently try to replace a textarea that does not work.

I found this simple example that gave me the clue.  Use div and append the ckeditor instead of using replace api call

http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/old/ajax.html

```
<div id='emailEditor1'>
              </div>

function closeTab() {
    emailEditor1.destroy();
    emailEditor1 = null;
}

function createEditor() 
    if (emailEditor1 == null) {
        emailEditor1 = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'emailEditor1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->widget('cms.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
    'target' => 'a#fancy-link',
    'config' => array( 'onClosed'=>'js:function(){for(name in CKEDITOR.instances){ CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);}}'
)));
```