# Find out the instance name AND destroy AND switch to source mode

Tags: jquery, replace, ckeditor, instance, destroy

I have three questions to the ckeditor

1. How can i find out the name of a ckeditor instance?
2. I want to destroy the instance ans switch back to a normal  without the ckeditor. In this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613215/how-to-properly-destroy-ckeditor-instance) is a example but it dont know the name of my instance.
3. How can i switch at all editors between the source code mode and wysiwyg mode?

Answer (score 2):

1. Instances are stored in `CKEDITOR.instances` object. You can iterate over this object and find anything you want. Instances are named after the id attribute of the textarea:

   `<textarea id="foo" ... </textarea>` will create the `CKEDITOR.instances.foo` instance.

   You can access your textarea by using `CKEDITOR.instances.foo.element` and  `CKEDITOR.instances.foo.element.$` (native DOM element).

   If there's no id specified, e.g. when you replace editors by the `ckeditor` class, subsequent names are as follows: `editor1, editor2, ... , editorN`
2. Once you know the id (see: 1.), you can simply do this:

   ```
   if ( CKEDITOR.instances.foo ) 
       CKEDITOR.instances.foo.destroy();
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'foo' );
   ```
3. `CKEDITOR.instances.foo.execCommand( 'source' )`