# CKEditor (in a SPA) freezes when navigating back to the editor page

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate CKEditor in a page of a SPA (Single Page Application).

CKEditor behaves correctly within the SPA page on the first visit, but not on next visits. For example, when pressing the backward browser arrow (to display the previous SPA page) and then the forward arrow (to display again the SPA page with CKEditor), CKEditor appears but the content has been erased and it's not reacting anymore. There is no carret when cliking on the text area. Also all API calls (such as setData() or resize()) have no effect anymore (whereas they were working on fist visit).

I presume CKEditor doesn't like its element to be removed from the DOM (that's what happens when switching to another page) and then be re-added to the DOM (that's what happens when visiting the page again).

**EDIT ON July 5 2017**

Thanks for your proposition to destroy CKEditor when leaving the page and to recreate it when navigating back, but this causes the lost of the editor state such as the the scrollbar position, the caret position, text selection, etc...

Ideally I would like to make it possible for a user to visit another page while he is in the middle of writing something in the editor (for example to check an information or copy a content from another page) and then to continue exactly where he was (no change on scrollbar, caret, selection,...) when he navigates back to the editor.

Is is possible?

Comment: I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykspc3mo/) to help reproducing the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly destroy CKeditor instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613215/how-to-properly-destroy-ckeditor-instance)

Comment: Thanks Marek but I'm looking for a better solution if possible (see my edit on July 5)

Comment: @Bruno please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Removing CKEditor just by removing its parent container like in your fiddle is not a good solution as CKEditor attaches some listeners to the DOM and by removing the container you are detaching those listeners which are not reattached then.

You should [destroy](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy) the editor before removing from DOM and then recreate it. Remember that destroying happens in an async manner so to know when it is finished you may listen to [destroy event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-destroy).

Here is modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1ames/hfbwu13t/) using `destroy` method (without handling `destroy` event which should be added).

**EDIT ON July 10 2017**

To preserve the state of the editor (scrollbar position, text selection, etc) between destroy - recreate, state of all this elements should be retained before destroying editor and then set after recreating it. It is doable, but requires some work and quite a lot of custom code.

> Ideally I would like to make it possible for a user to visit another page while he is in the middle of writing something in the editor

Since you are creating a SPA application, for the above the better solution will be to use some floating/fixed container in which CKEditor is placed and which does not reload with rest of the page upon navigation (e.g. the same as Facebook chat works).

Also remember that recreating CKEditor takes some time (very short, but it may be still visible) so on every page navigation it will be visible for the user that something is happening with the editor even though its state does not changed.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a better solution if possible (see my edit on July 5)