# How to destroy ckeditor in an angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have an angular4 app that generates ckeditor elements in different angular routes. When I go to route A, the ckedtior successfully databinds to data defined in the component that contains the ckeditor. If I go to route b and then come back to route a, the data binding does not work anymore. If I look in the console I see the following error:

> [Warning] [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to
>   http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-destroy-iframe
>   (ckeditor.js, line 21)

When I go to the link it says

> Location: plugins/wysiwygarea/plugin.js Description: The editor's
>    could not be destroyed correctly because it had been unloaded
>   before the editor was destroyed. Make sure to destroy the editor
>   before detaching it from the DOM. Additional data: None.

I feel like based on this I would like to implement an OnDestroy method, and destroy the editor when the component is destroyed. But I don't know how to do this, and it is not clear from the link. How do you destroy ckeditor in an angular4 app? Or avoid this problem via some other way?

Comment: Destroy the editor instance inside the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook from your component. [DOCS](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#component-lifecycle-hooks-overview)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how do I destroy the editor instance? I know how to implement an ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613307/2545680

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked was here...It was the post all the way at the bottom...

https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/24